# Ho to determine docker container port number?

Tags: c#, asp.net, docker

ASP.NET application is deployed to a docker container. I.e., it is accessible via:

http://10.98.1.191:1673/webapp/start

From the back-end side, I need to determine port number. I used following ways to get the port:

```
HttpRequest request = _httpRequestVariable;
var host1 = request.ServerVariables["SERVER_NAME"]; // 10.98.1.191
var port1 = request.ServerVariables["SERVER_PORT"]; // getting port 80
var host2 = request.Url.Host; // 10.98.1.191
var port2 = request.Url.Port; // getting port 80
```

Above I expected to get port 1673, but in both cases I'm getting default port 80. The issue with a wrong port number is appearing on the docker container only. What is the correct way to extract port number from the calling URL?

Answer (score 2):

If you are on the machine where the docker container is running, run

> docker ps

in your terminal. That will give you  list of all running docker containers. Then run

> docker inspect [name of docker container]

That will give you all the stats for that docker container, including port numbers.

Answer (score 1):

try to use the following command from command line in machine where docker is running

```
docker container ls --all
```

it should display a list of all used ports